# Can't figure out how to print only amount of fibonacci numbers user asks for

Tags: assembly, mips

The user should input a number between (3-30) and the program should output however many fibonacci calculations they asked for. My program is printing all 30 fibonacci numbers. I know I have it set at 30, but that is to see if my calculations were correct. I am using MIPS assembly language.

```
  .data
my_string: .asciiz "How many Fibonacci numbers you would like to calculate (3-30): "
fibs: .word   3 : 30       
size: .word  30             
space:.asciiz  " "
head: .asciiz  "The Fibonacci numbers are:\n"

.text
.globl main
main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, my_string
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall

move $v0, $t7

    la   $t0, fibs        # load array
    la   $t5, size        
    lw   $t5, 0($t5)      
    li   $t2, 1           
    add.d $f0, $f2, $f4
    sw   $t2, 0($t0)      
    sw   $t2, 4($t0)      
    addi $t1, $t5, -2     
loop: 
lw   $t3, 0($t0)       # get values from array
    lw   $t4, 4($t0)      
    add  $t2, $t3, $t4    
    sw   $t2, 8($t0)      
    addi $t0, $t0, 4      
    addi $t1, $t1, -1     
    bgtz $t1, loop        
    la   $a0, fibs        
    add  $a1, $zero, $t5  
    jal  print            
    li   $v0, 10         
    syscall   

#print loop numbers

print:
add  $t0, $zero, $a0  
add  $t1, $zero, $a1  
la   $a0, head        
li   $v0, 4           
syscall

out:  
lw   $a0, 0($t0)     
    li   $v0, 1         
    syscall

    la   $a0, space       
    li   $v0, 4           
    syscall

    addi $t0, $t0, 4      
    addi $t1, $t1, -1     
    bgtz $t1, out         
    jr$31
```

Comment: So this code works correctly, and you're asking how to modify it to only print the first N?  You already have loops, so you should just set `$t5` from user input instead of from a constant, right?  Or just modify the memory that your existing code loads from.  Can you be more specific about where you're getting stuck figuring out how to do that?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean that the program should output "however many fibonacci calculations they asked for"? Does that mean the number of primitive multiply/add operations?

Comment: The user inputs a number between 3 and 30. The program should calculate however many numbers they asked for and print them out.

Comment: Yes, you already said that in the question.  But your question sounds like it's just asking for someone to implement it for you.  You haven't said anything about what you've tried yourself.  Instead, you just showed a program that ignores the user input on purpose.  I don't see a question here other than "write the code for me", which is not a good question.  Lucky for you, though it looks like Margaret was willing to spend time explaining a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you find yourself confused about a program you can use this strategy:

1. Skim through the program to get the main idea of what it do.
   Just look for functional blocks, for example: "*There should be a loop somewhere...*" or "*Where does it make jumps?*".
   You don't have to get a clear idea of the program, just divide it into main sections.
   Sometimes you have to take guesses.
2. Starting from the first section, comment and reverse engineer each section.
   You may need to comment single instructions or small instruction group.
   Pay particular attention to how registers are used, what value each register holds.
3. Step through the program with a debugger.
   This will help you in the most difficult situations and when working with lengthy or tricky program.

---

In our case the program is so simple that we can stop at step 2:

```
.data
   #Strings

   my_string: 
      .asciiz "How many Fibonacci numbers you would like to calculate (3-30): "
   space:
      .asciiz  " "
   head: 
      .asciiz  "The Fibonacci numbers are:\n"

   #Array of fibonacci numbers
   fibs: .word   3 : 30       

   #Size    
   size: .word  30             

.text
.globl main

main:

   #Print string
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, my_string
   syscall

   #Read integer into v0
   li $v0, 5
   syscall

   #Overwrite v0 with t7
   #Faulty code!
   move $v0, $t7

   #Load address of fibonacci array into t0
   la   $t0, fibs        # load array

   #t0 = Current address into Fibonacci array

   #Load size into t5 (MIPS is RISC, no load-from-immediate-address instruction ava)
   la   $t5, size        #Load address of size into t5   
   lw   $t5, 0($t5)      #Load word from t5 

   #t5 = Number of numbers to compute

   #Load first (and second, they are equal) Fibonacci number into t2
   li   $t2, 1    

   #Totally unrelated FB instruction?
   #Remove this!    
   add.d $f0, $f2, $f4

   #Store the first and second Fibonacci number into...
   sw   $t2, 0($t0)    #... the first   
   sw   $t2, 4($t0)    #... and second array position (each position is 4 byte)

   #Set t1 = t5 - 2 = size = 2
   #t1 is the number of numbers left to compute, we skip the first two we already computed (thus the -2)
   addi $t1, $t5, -2

   #t1 = Number of numbers left to do

   loop: 
      #t0 points to the second from last number in the array

      #Get the second from last number from the array
      lw   $t3, 0($t0)       # get values from array
      #Get the last number from the array
      lw   $t4, 4($t0)      

      #Compute the next Fib number into t2
      add  $t2, $t3, $t4    
      #Store it into the array (at fibs[t0+2])
      sw   $t2, 8($t0)  

      #Advance t0 to point to the next number
      addi $t0, $t0, 4  

      #Decrement the counter (number left to compute)    
      addi $t1, $t1, -1  

   #Jump if t1>0 back to the start of the loop   
   bgtz $t1, loop  

   #Call print with the array address and number of items
   la   $a0, fibs        
   add  $a1, $zero, $t5  
   jal  print  

   #Exit     
   li   $v0, 10         
   syscall   

#print loop numbers

print:
   #Mov arguments to t0 and t1
   add  $t0, $zero, $a0  
   add  $t1, $zero, $a1  

   #Print string
   la   $a0, head        
   li   $v0, 4           
   syscall

   out:  
      #Load number from array and print it
      lw   $a0, 0($t0)     
      li   $v0, 1         
      syscall

      #Print space
      la   $a0, space       
      li   $v0, 4           
      syscall

      #Move t0 to the next number (each number occupies 4 bytes)
      addi $t0, $t0, 4    
      #Decrement the number left to do  
      addi $t1, $t1, -1 

    #If t1 > 0 jump back to the start of the loop (out)   
    bgtz $t1, out  

    #Return       
    jr $31
```

Not accounting for the non relevant instructions here and there, the register usage at the start of the loop is:

> t0 = Address of the second from last computed number
>   t0 + 4 = Address of the last computer number
>   t1 = Numbers left to do
>   t5 = Total number of numbers to compute

Also `t1 = t5 - 2`.

So it should be easy to make this program works with a size from the user.

Just change `move $v0, $t7` (Which is faulty because moves t7 into v0, overwriting the only place where the number from the user is stored!) with

```
#Store v0 into size
la $t5, size
sw $v0, 0($t5)
```

---

You should notice that this program won't work for input less that 1.
You can fix it as an exercise.